# jQuery find name of clicked button by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 tables with buttons and they have the same name class like this

```
<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 1</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 3</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

i need when i click in one of this buttons i get the value of span for example if i click in the first button i get this value Some Text 1 i used some jquery code but in the result they give me all value

```
 $(".howdy",this).click(function(e) {
        cart=$(".info").text();
        console.log(cart);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.howdy').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('table').find('.info').text());
});
```

You start travesring from `$('.howdy')` button and looking for closest `<table>` then you looking for `.info` class inside and getting the `.text()`

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uh9yw7df/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
cart = $(this).parents("table").find('.info').text();
```

instead of

```
cart=$(".info").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```js
$('.howdy').click(function(){
  var cart = $(this).closest('table').find('.info').text();
  console.log(cart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 1</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 3</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

The problem with your original jQuery, was:

```
$(".howdy",this).click(function(e) {
    // you were selecting without any context, so retrieving
    // all the .info elements, but the getter use of text()
    // retrieves from only the first element of the collection:
    cart=$(".info").text();
    console.log(cart);
});
```

Also: `$('.howdy', this)` is a contextual selector, looking for the `.howdy` element(s) inside of the context `this`. In this case `this` (probably) referred to the global object, the `window`, which *works* here (or should, depending on what precisely `this` is), but can cause problems.

Incidentally, an alternative to the above is:

```js
$('.howdy').click(function(){
    var cart = $('.info').eq($(this).index('.howdy')).text();
    console.log(cart);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 1</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 3</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

But this is a little over-complicated for such a simple task.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: $(this).index('.howdy') inside the click on howdy? I would think $(this).index() enough

Comment: But `$(this).index()` gives the index of the element amongst its siblings (as I'm sure you know), and even inside of an event-handling method, there's no implicit reference to the original selector; and so will *always* return `1`, and will always return the text of the first `.info` element on the page: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p1p6m38g/).

Comment: Ok. I have never used index this way

Answer (score 0):

To get the nearest info before the button, you can also travel up and get the prev() sibling of the row- that way you can have the rows in the same table

```js
    $(".howdy").click(function(e) {
        var cart=$(this).closest("tr").prev().find(".info").text();
        window.console&&console.log(cart);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 1</span></td> </tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 2</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr><td><span class="info">Some Text 3</span></td></tr>
<tr><td><button class="howdy">print out</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Downvoting without commenting is pure harassment.